# Write "Some Apples are red, but not any red apple is green" in Predicate form?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

Some apples are red, but not any red apple is green

Dictionary:

Ax : An object is an Apple

Rx : An object is red

Gx : An object is green

I have assigned the "but" in the question  to the logical Operater ∧, so I wrote this:

∀x(∃x(Ax ∧ Rx) ∧ ∀x((Ax ∧ Rx) → -Gx))

Which I think reads as: For any X, There is at least one object that is an apple and is red, and for any x, If an object is an apple and is red, then the object is not green.

Is this correct?

Comment: This makes sense!

Comment: Not sure if sarcasm but I edited my question to make more sense. @peter

Comment: This was not meant sarcastic.

Comment: The outer ∀x is not needed.